# Click OK in Dialog box display output text in SDI

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I have a dialog box displayed when I press a menu item in the SDI window. In the Dialog box When i press OK button it should display "SUCESS" in the SDI window... In ONVIEW() i have to use `pDC->TEXTOUT()` but how to execute that statement on pressing OK button.. I am using visual C++ 6

Comment: I am creating an SDI application. I am having a dialog box attached to menu. When i click the dialog box open and does processing and a 2D vector lies in the dialog pushbutton function. How do i send it to ONDRAW function defined in VIEW.CPP file There i will plot this vector in terms of pixels.. Can u please suggest me with small example code to be written in pushbutton() and ONDRAW().. I would be highly thankful to u.. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

you should define a user defined message and use PostMessage to call your method in SDI Window.

Comment: can u provide me if any sample example codes if possible.. Actually i am using it for some other purpose for plotting pixels. That would really help me a lot... Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1432369: Is it a modal dialog or modeless

Comment: I am creating an SDI application. I am having a dialog box attached to menu. When i click the dialog box open and does processing and a 2D vector lies in the dialog pushbutton function. How do i send it to ONDRAW function defined in VIEW.CPP file There i will plot this vector in terms of pixels.. Can u please suggest me with small example code to be written in pushbutton() and ONDRAW().. I would be highly thankful to u.. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on assumption that your dialog is modal.

You do not have to define or send any messages.
Retrieve data from the dialog.

Presumably you store 2D vector data in some kind of an array declared as a member variable of the dialog.

When OK button is pushed and copy data to a view’s member variable of the same type. Use it to draw whatever you desire.

```
void CSDIPopupSampleView::OnViewDialog() 
{
    CSimpleDlg dlg;

    int iResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if(IDOK == iResponse)
    {
        //Copy data from a dialog here.
    }

    Invalidate(); // this will cause redraw
}
```